# Checklist while upgrading Access to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, database-design, upgrade

I have 4 MS Access database that needs to be upgraded to MS SQL Server database. The 4 MS Access database contains 10 tables each, comprising of 40 tables in total. Hence, should I develop one SQL Server database which contain all the 40 tables Or should I have 4 different SQL Server database that contain their respective tables?

In a broader sense, what things should a SQL Developer should keep in his mind while upgrading to SQL Server from MS Access (or any other database)?

Answer (score 0):

Depends, are the 4 Access databases functionally different?

If they interrelate, put all 40 tables in the same database.
If you need separation, for security or otherwise, then 4 Databases with 10 tables each.